# Scaling differences between chrome and other browsers

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, scaling

My clients website and others are appearing hugely zoomed in on Chrome compared to other browsers on WINDOWS only (specifically Microsoft EDGE).

All browsers on Mac OS are displaying the website correctly at the correct scale.

Can anyone help explain what's going on here.

The website is https://emirat.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

I just tried that website on my browsers and it looks the same on everyone...

Stupid question, but it may work: do you maybe have a default zoom for Edge?

EDIT: this is how it looks for me

[image: edge results]

Comment: Hi Fabio,
on EDGE the browser is displaying by default at 150%, I've been decreasing this to 100% to match all the other browsers which are at 100% by default.

The website should display the header with about 1/2 of the blue boxes below showing above the fold. Is this how it's displaying for you or is the header filling the whole page with a huge menu bar?

Comment: @Luc_Gibson I updated the answer with a screenshot - does it look right?

Comment: Looks absolutely fine. I'll have a play around and figure out what's going on over here. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since Chrome 71, Chrome started scaling according to the setting the user had in Window, which is not the case for edge. you can force chrome to ignore windows setting by running chrome with:

`/high-dpi-support=1 /device-scale-factor=1.125`

or set the windows scaling to 100%.